# Multiple instances of GeoServer sharing the same data dir

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to achieve the following : https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/clustering/clustering/passive/passive.html.

I have 2 instances of GeoServer sharing the same data directory (containing config/catalog). I see that, when adding a layer, store, workspace,... to 1 instance, the other instance gets updated when I reload the config through rest/UI. Except for global.xml and logging.xml (from what I tested), I see only those files that are not updated when I call the rest reload on the second instance.

Could you please advise on the correct way to synchronize the config/catalog between the different instances ?

Comment: I'm looking for the same objective, do you have any updates?